# BeyondCompare4 update session defaults doesn't work

Tags: encoding, beyondcompare4

I changed the encoding of my project from gbk to UTF-8,
then I use beyondcompare4(Version 4.2.3) to make sure they(two folders) are only encoding differences.

however,every time I open the old file in the compare left side, new in right.
file in left side shows [western european] encoding, 
I have to select ANSI repeatedly, or some chinese words will be messy.
file in right will auto-detect UTF-8,which very nice.

**I want to set just one time, then enabled to remaining file.**

**so I use the session settings below, not work,
I tried [update for all the files within parent session], not work too.**
[image]

it will change back,,
[image]

Are there any good ideas can compare file ignore encoding,
or just show the file in right encoding ?

Answer (score 0):

Only session settings in the **Importance**, **Alignment**, and **Replacements** tabs can be set as session defaults.

To see what session settings can be set as defaults, open Beyond Compare to the Home view. In the **Sessions** list on the left side, expand **New**. Select **Text Compare**. Then click the **Edit Defaults** button.

A character encoding override that affects all comparisons can be set in a file format. To set the encoding, open **Tools | File Formats**. Select the format with a mask that matches your files. Go to the **Conversion** tab. Change the **Encoding** dropdown from **Detect** to your preferred encoding.

Encoding overrides in file formats affect both sides, it isn't possible to assign a global encoding override that is side specific.